# Emacs highlights every new character I type (Common Lisp with Slime)

Tags: text, emacs, common-lisp, highlight, slime

I'm new to Emacs and I use it to code in Common Lisp with Slime. Everything was ok but this morning when I tried to edit a lisp file it highlights every visible character I type for no reason (but not the white spaces.) When I save the file, quit Emacs and restart it, the text is not highlighted but, again, every new character I type is. It just happens to lisp files so I suspect Slime to cause that but it never did that before.

[example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qcGC.png)

Here "(def" was saved in the file and the rest is what I typed after reloading Emacs.

Thanks for your help :)

**Edit:**

`C-u C-x =` gives [c-u c-x =](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHrMy.png)

Comment: What does `C-u C-x =` say about text properties / overlays for the highlighted text?

Comment: See SLIME manual [8.17 Highlight Edits](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Highlight-Edits.html#Highlight-Edits).

Comment: It worked thank you! :)

Comment: @jkiiski: please add it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highlight is caused by the [slime-highlight-edits](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Highlight-Edits.html#Highlight-Edits) minor mode, which helps you find edited regions of the file (that may need compiling). It can be toggled on and off with

```
M-x slime-highlight-edits-mode
```